# при использовании gulp не могу импортировать библиотеки из node_modules

Tags: javascript, gulp

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
использую gulp для сборки, вот так он работает с js

```
function scripts() {
  return src('src/app/index.js')
    .pipe(include({ hardFail: true }))
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['@babel/env'],
    }))
    .pipe(dest(`${stageDirname}/js/`))
    .pipe(localServer.stream())
}
```

и вот мне нужно из node_modules импортировать библу, но после сборки я получаю ошибку в index.js  "require is not defined"

пробовал import, пробовал require, пробовал указывать type: "modules"/"commonjs" в package.json , но все бестолку